# Ссылки в ответе ведут на вопрос вместо URL указанного в markdown

Tags: дефект, markdown

В ответе https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/368751/202, первые четыре ссылки ведут на вопрос вместо http://hackage.haskell.org,

[image: ссылка ведет не туда]

В предпросмотре при редактировании все нормально:

[image: предпросмотр все нормально]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Похоже на ошибку миграции. После «пустой» правки ссылки стали работать правильно.

Часть причины этой ошибки в том, что для оптимизации хранится как исходный код, так и отрендеренный текст вопроса. При правке текст рендерится заново.

Comment: Интересно, что проблема была только со ссылками, в которых внутри был `блок кода`.

Comment: Теперь понятно, откуда растут ноги у нередактируемых (слишком коротких, чью длину приходится наращивать для принятия правки), но успешно созданных в своё время сообщений.

Comment: @Arhad да, именно так. На Хэшкоде вообще были допустимы вопросы, имеющие только заголовок. :)